# Check variable to set class value at runtime C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i've the following code, it's supposed to check if a variable from a DataList (Month) it's the same as a variable called mesActual, they're text (Like December/November)

```
      <li id="Li1" class='<%# (Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToString(Eval("Month")) == Convert.ToString(mesActual))) ? "activa" : "no-activa" %>'>
           <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn" runat="server" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Month")%>'><%#Eval("Month")%></asp:LinkButton>
           <div class="btn"><span><asp:Label ID="lbltot" runat="server"></asp:Label></span></div>
      </li>
```

On page load, it seems to work, first item is selected and assigned the class "activa", but when i click on the button, it reloads the page, i can see my variable "mesActual" changed, but the class of the li doesn't change.
I'm missing something?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try comparing using Equals method instead of the == operator.  This will compare the string values as opposed to references.

Also you do not need to wrap it in Convert.ToBoolean() as the result of the Equals method will return a bool.

Eval("Month").Equals(Convert.ToString(mesActual)) ? "activa" : "no-activa"

Comment: Thanks! didn't know about .Equals, but it doesn't seem to affect the result :( - it is here http://agenda.koncepto.com/Default.aspx -

Comment: The `string` type declares an `==` operator which performs value comparison. So long as the objects are typed as `string` then `==` and `Equals` will return the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try `runat="server"`, `<%# %>` only fires on `DataBind()`:

```
<li id="Li1" runat="server" class='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("Month")) == Convert.ToString(mesActual) ? "activa" : "no-activa" %>'>
```

Answer (score 0):

What type is mesActual ? and how and when are you setting the value of it.

If you tried:

```
   <li id="Li1" runat="server" class='<%# (Eval("Month").ToString().Equals( mesActual)) ? "activa" : "no-activa" %>'
```

And it did not work, have you verified the value of the Eval("Month") and variable mesActual, actually are the same at some point?

Cheers.